# Github - how to include info in your source

Tags: git, version-control, keyword-expansion

Is their a way to inject last commit number/branch information into your code files in github? Maybe using some kind of reserved word or token? I'm a little new to advanced source control and git so forgive if I'm not using the right terminology and feel free to rephrase question.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? why do you need this?

Comment: This isn't about github, it's about git. Either git has a way to do keyword expansion or it does not.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes but it isn't recommended.

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Does_git_have_keyword_expansion.3F

Answer (score 1):

See [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Does_git_have_keyword_expansion.3F) for keyword expansion.  The solution is to add an ident entry to [.gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_tt_ident_tt) about which files should be modified on checkin/checkout:

> When the attribute ident is set for a path, git replaces $Id$ in the
>   blob object with $Id:, followed by the 40-character hexadecimal blob
>   object name, followed by a dollar sign $ upon checkout. Any byte
>   sequence that begins with $Id: and ends with $ in the worktree file is
>   replaced with $Id$ upon check-in.

Comment: but is there are more meaningful (to the end user) thing that resembles a version # than $id$

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible through your build system. In your build scripts you can execute git commands to get the necessary information and then pass these as macros in your code.